# How to count the total number of values from various rows, when each row has multiple data seperated by comma?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with only 1 column. Each row/cell in the table contains a number of values separated by commas. Some cells contain NULL (no value). I want to get the number total number of values in all the rows. (Using php & mysql)

---

### | Table  |

### | 32,33  |

### |   21   |

### |  NULL  |

### |45,61,52|

Hence the total number of data should be 6, i.e 2 in 1st row, 1 in 2nd row & 3 in 4th row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using php **extract all the values in an array**  and use **explode** to get the total number of values.

```
$i=0;
while(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0)
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $result))
  {
    $data_elements = explode(',',$row['data']); // extract all the comma seperated value in array
    $i += count($data_elements); //count them all
  }
}
echo $i; // these are your total number of values
```

hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man!!!
Worked wonders, only I had to remove the outer while loop ("while(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0)", was causing problems).

Answer (score 3):

The value count will be +1 than comma count. But if a column doesn't have comma, it should be zero. So this will work:

```
SELECT sum(LENGTH('col1') - LENGTH(REPLACE('col1', ',', ''))+1) AS total 
FROM table1 WHERE LENGTH('col1')>0
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes comma indicates one value

```
    SELECT sum(LENGTH('field1') - LENGTH(REPLACE('field1', ',', ''))+1) 
AS comma_sum from table1
```

Test this and let me know how it goes

Comment: 3 values will only contain 2 commas. This counts the number of commas